# Segmentation fault when commenting 2 free (Sokoban game)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fault

I've been trying to solve a segmentation fault since yesterday, it's driving me crazy...
So I've got this program that I use to implement the sokoban game, in which a map is given, and a plan like "NSEW" is given, meaning that I want the player to move north, then south, then etc... on the map given.

```
map* replay(map* map_loaded, int length, char* plan){
    map* new_map=move(map_loaded,plan[0]);
    map* old_map=deep_copy(new_map);
    for (int i=1 ; i<length ; i++){
        free(new_map->p_char);
        free(new_map);
        new_map=move(old_map,plan[i]);
        free(old_map->p_char);
        free(old_map);
        old_map=deep_copy(new_map);
    }
    free(old_map->p_char);
    free(old_map);
    return new_map;
}
```

Map is a structure defined as following :

```
typedef struct map map;
struct map{
    int width;
    int height;
    char* p_char;
};
```

The move function does one movement ;

The deep_copy makes a deep copy of a map struct :

```
map* deep_copy(map* map_loaded){

    map* new_map=malloc(sizeof(map));

    char* p_array=map_loaded->p_char;
    int width=map_loaded->width;
    int height=map_loaded->height;
    new_map->width=width;
    new_map->height=height;

    char* p_new=malloc(sizeof(char)*width*height);
    for (int i=0 ; i<width*height ; i++){
        p_new[i]=p_array[i];
    }
    new_map->p_char=p_new;
    return(new_map);
}
```

And what happens is that if I leave the code like that, if the length chosen ( the number of movements I want the player to do) is too high (depends on the map and the movements), when executing a replay.c program :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You must provide a file name or enough elements!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    map* map_loaded=load(argv[1]);

    int length=atoi(argv[2]);

    char* plan=argv[3];


    map* new_map=replay(map_loaded,length,plan);
    print_map(new_map);

    free(new_map->p_char);
    free(new_map);
    free(map_loaded->p_char);
    free(map_loaded);
    return 1;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault... But if I do :

```
//free(old_map->p_char);
//free(old_map);
```

Everything works perfect !!
I really don't understand why... The problem is if I do those free valgrind tells me I don't have as many free as allocs, which is normal...

I would really appreciate any help given...
Thanks in advance if you've been brave enough to read me until this point !

Edit : 
Here is my move function ;

```
   map* move(map* map_loaded, char dir){
    int pos=Position(map_loaded);
    int width=map_loaded->width;

    map* new_map=deep_copy(map_loaded);
    char* p_new_array=new_map->p_char;


    switch(dir){
        case 'N':
        if (p_new_array[pos-width]=='#'){ // Si il y a un mur au dessus
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos-width]=='$' && p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='$')
              ||(p_new_array[pos-width]=='$' && p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='*') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos-width]=='*' && p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='$') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos-width]=='*' && p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='*')){ //s'il y a 2 caisses au dessus
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos-width]=='$' && p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='#') //s'il y a une caisse au niveau -1 et un mur au niveau -2
              ||(p_new_array[pos-width]=='*' && p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='#')){
                return(map_loaded);
            }

            // On vérifie d'abord s'il y a une caisse à déplacer

            if (p_new_array[pos-width]=='$' || p_new_array[pos-width]=='*'){
                if (p_new_array[pos-2*width]=='.'){
                    p_new_array[pos-2*width]='*';
                }   
                else {
                    p_new_array[pos-2*width]='$';
                }

                if (p_new_array[pos-width]=='*'){
                    p_new_array[pos-width]='.';
                }
                else{
                    p_new_array[pos-width]=' ';
                }   
            }


            //On change le char en position du joueur 

            if (p_new_array[pos]=='+'){
                p_new_array[pos-width]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]='.';

            }
            else if (p_new_array[pos-width]=='.'){
                p_new_array[pos-width]='+';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            }
            else {
                p_new_array[pos-width]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            } 
            break;



        case 'S':
        if (p_new_array[pos+width]=='#'){ // Si il y a un mur en dessous
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos+width]=='$' && p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='$')
              ||(p_new_array[pos+width]=='$' && p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='*') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos+width]=='*' && p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='$') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos+width]=='*' && p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='*')){//s'il y a 2 caisses au dessus
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos+width]=='$' && p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='#') //s'il y a une caisse au niveau +1 et un mur au niveau +2
              ||(p_new_array[pos+width]=='*' && p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='#')){
                return(map_loaded);
            }
             // On vérifie d'abord s'il y a une caisse à déplacer

            if (p_new_array[pos+width]=='$' || p_new_array[pos+width]=='*'){
                if (p_new_array[pos+2*width]=='.'){
                    p_new_array[pos+2*width]='*';
                }   
                else {
                    p_new_array[pos+2*width]='$';
                }

                if (p_new_array[pos+width]=='*'){
                    p_new_array[pos+width]='.';
                }
                else{
                    p_new_array[pos+width]=' ';
                }   
            }

             //On change le char en position du joueur 

            if (p_new_array[pos]=='+'){
                p_new_array[pos+width]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]='.';

            }
            else if (p_new_array[pos+width]=='.'){
                p_new_array[pos+width]='+';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            }
            else {
                p_new_array[pos+width]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            } 
            break;




        case 'W':
        if (p_new_array[pos-1]=='#'){ // Si il y a un mur en dessous
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos-1]=='$' && p_new_array[pos-2]=='$')
              ||(p_new_array[pos-1]=='$' && p_new_array[pos-2]=='*') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos-1]=='*' && p_new_array[pos-2]=='$') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos-1]=='*' && p_new_array[pos-2]=='*')){ //s'il y a 2 caisses à gauche
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos-1]=='$' && p_new_array[pos-2]=='#') //s'il y a une caisse au niveau -1 et un mur au niveau -2
              ||(p_new_array[pos-1]=='*' && p_new_array[pos-2]=='#')){
                return(map_loaded);
            }

            // On vérifie d'abord s'il y a une caisse à déplacer

            if (p_new_array[pos-1]=='$' || p_new_array[pos-1]=='*'){
                if (p_new_array[pos-2]=='.'){
                    p_new_array[pos-2]='*';
                }   
                else {
                    p_new_array[pos-2]='$';
                }

                if (p_new_array[pos-1]=='*'){
                    p_new_array[pos-1]='.';
                }
                else{
                    p_new_array[pos-1]=' ';
                }   
            }


            //On change le char en position du joueur 

            if (p_new_array[pos]=='+'){
                p_new_array[pos-1]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]='.';

            }
            else if (p_new_array[pos-1]=='.'){
                p_new_array[pos-1]='+';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            }
            else {
                p_new_array[pos-1]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            } 
            break;


        case 'E':
        if (p_new_array[pos+1]=='#') {// Si il y a un mur à droite
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos+1]=='$' && p_new_array[pos+2]=='$')
              ||(p_new_array[pos+1]=='$' && p_new_array[pos+2]=='*') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos+1]=='*' && p_new_array[pos+2]=='$') 
              ||(p_new_array[pos+1]=='*' && p_new_array[pos+2]=='*')){ //s'il y a 2 caisses à droite
                return(map_loaded);
            }
            if ((p_new_array[pos+1]=='$' && p_new_array[pos+2]=='#') //s'il y a une caisse au niveau +1 et un mur au niveau +2
              ||(p_new_array[pos+1]=='*' && p_new_array[pos+2]=='#')){
                return(map_loaded);
            }

            // On vérifie d'abord s'il y a une caisse à déplacer

            if (p_new_array[pos+1]=='$' || p_new_array[pos+1]=='*'){
                if (p_new_array[pos+2]=='.'){
                    p_new_array[pos+2]='*';
                }   
                else {
                    p_new_array[pos+2]='$';
                }

                if (p_new_array[pos+1]=='*'){
                    p_new_array[pos+1]='.';
                }
                else{
                    p_new_array[pos+1]=' ';
                }   
            }


            //On change le char en position du joueur 

            if (p_new_array[pos]=='+'){
                p_new_array[pos+1]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]='.';

            }
            else if (p_new_array[pos+1]=='.'){
                p_new_array[pos+1]='+';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            }
            else {
                p_new_array[pos+1]='@';
                p_new_array[pos]=' ';
            } 
            break;

        }
    return(new_map);
}
```

And here is the load function ;

```
char* Array_Creator(char* filename){
    FILE* p_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char* p_array = NULL;
    if (p_file == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{   
        size_t size=1;
        int c;
        while (getc(p_file)!=EOF) {
            size++;
        }
        fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_SET);
        while ((c=getc(p_file))!='\n' && c!=EOF) { //on se débarasse de la première ligne
            size--;
        }
        p_array=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
        if (p_array!=NULL) { //si jamais le malloc ne fonctionne pas
            for(size_t i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
            p_array[i]=(char)getc(p_file);


            if (p_array[i] == '\n') { // si le caractère est une nouvelle ligne, on s'en sépare
                i--; // on ajuste alors la taille et l'indice
                size--;
                }
            }
            p_array[size-1]='\0';
        }
        fclose(p_file);
    }
    return p_array;
}

//La fonction Dimensions permet de récupérer les dimensions d'une map

couple Dimensions(char *p_char){

    FILE *p_file = NULL;
    p_file=fopen(p_char, "r");

    if (p_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read file %s!\n", p_char);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    couple dim={0,0}; //la structure couple est déf dans le loader.h

    int width         = 0;
    int height        = 0;
    int fscanf_result = 0;

    fscanf_result = fscanf(p_file, "%d %d\n", &width, &height);
    if (fscanf_result != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "First line is not syntactically correct!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dim.x=width;
    dim.y=height;
    fclose(p_file);
    return dim;
}


//La fonction Load est celle demandée et permettant de charger une carte ; elle utilise Dimensions et Array_Creator

map* load(char *filename){
    map* map_loaded=malloc(sizeof(map)); //on alloue dynamiquement la map

    //Dans un premier temps on récupère les dimensions

    couple map_dim={0,0};  
    map_dim=Dimensions(filename);
    map_loaded->width=map_dim.x;
    map_loaded->height=map_dim.y;

    //Dans un second temps on définit le tableau 1D contenant l'ensemble des éléments de la map

    char* p_char=Array_Creator(filename);
    map_loaded->p_char=p_char;
    return map_loaded;
}
```

The command line is, for example :
./replay ./data/soko.in 4 7"NSWSESNWW"

Comment: It sounds like you are corrupting your heap. valgrind should be telling you when you do an invalid write. If not, then try setting all pointers to NULL immediately after you free them - that way if you try to access freed memory you'll get an immediate error.

Comment: You haven't posted the `move` function

Comment: No I haven't posted the move function cause it's really long, there are many cases, it's like 200 hundreds lines long... But what you should know is that it takes a map, and returns a new one !

Comment: @CandideThovexo The `move` is important as it must do some `malloc` calls. Strip it down so that it just handles a single case that expose the error.

Comment: Done ! And Paul R to answer you, I've done what you said but it didn't change anything...

Comment: OT: It seems you get `length` from `argv[2]` and the moves to make from `argv[3]`. That means that you have to trust that the user gives you "valid" input... that's a bad idea. Would be better to get `length` from `strlen(argv[3])`

Comment: Actually the idea is you don't have to execute all the moves, if you want to only execute the first move from the plan "NSEW" you are allowed to do so if argv[2]=1... But whenever I got a segmentation fault I had made sure that the lenght was valid...

Comment: The `move` function is incomplete. We also need the `load` function. The posted code does **not** show the error. So unless you update the question, we can't help. BTW: We also need the exact command line used for executing the program.

Comment: Done ! But actually the project contains many files, maybe it would be easier if I could upload the folder containing all the files... How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In the `move` function, should change all

```
return(map_loaded); => return(new_map);
```

It will map_loaded to be freed twice when the move function returns map_loaded

Code analysis

```
map *replay(map *map_loaded, int length, char *plan)
{
    map *new_map = move(map_loaded, plan[0]); // [2] set new_map to map_loaded
    map *old_map = deep_copy(new_map);
    for (int i = 1 ; i < length ; i++) {
        free(new_map->p_char);
        free(new_map);                        // [3] new_map be freed, 
                                              // equivalent map_loaded be freed
        new_map = move(old_map, plan[i]);
        ...
    }
    ...
    return new_map;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    ...
    map *map_loaded = load(argv[1]);         // [1] map_loaded be malloc
    ...
    map *new_map = replay(map_loaded, length, plan);
    ...
    free(map_loaded->p_char);
    free(map_loaded);                        // [4] map_loaded be freed
    ...
}
```

Comment: Of course it was the problem... Thank you so much, it works perfectly !!

Comment: @CandideThovexo: if the answer solved your problem you should mark it as “accepted” (click on the check mark), and an up-vote would be polite too.